# move() method in paddle game

Tags: java, methods

Currently implementing the move() method for the ball class in my paddle game.
The paddle game is the one with the paddle on the bottom, that can move left/right. And the ball bounces off of the three walls. I realize that my move method is wrong, wondering if someone can point to me the right way to go about implementing it. I need to account for when the ball bounces off the sides and top

EDIT: I played around with my code but it's still not bouncing off the walls

My code:

```
    if (this.y+speed<=0+radius)     //Checking for top          
    {
        System.out.println("in y"); //Checking if it's in this condition
        flipYDir();  


    }
    else if (this.x+speed<=0+radius) //Checking for left wall
    {
        System.out.println("in x<"); //Checking if it's in this condition
        flipXDir();


    }
    else if (this.x+speed<courtWidth-radius) //Checking for right wall
    {
        System.out.println("in x>"); //Checking if it's in this condition
        flipXDir();

    }
    else  //Update move
    {
    x+=speed*xDir;
    y+=speed*yDir;
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? Have you tried using it and if so what is it doing that's wrong?

Comment: I have a tester class provided by my instructor. The tester says the bouncing at the top is incorrect, and the bouncing on the left is incorrect. But for some reason bouncing at the right is correct.

Comment: You might want to provide the correct behaviour as it is described, hopefully, but your instructur. Also you might want to create a trace of your code's behaviour by inserting a couple of print statements showing the `x`, `y`, `speed` and `dir` values in each step. Also, it could be the problem lies outside the move method. Finally, but not really related to your problem, I'd implement `xSpeed` and `ySpeed` so your first two `if/then` clauses collapse to `x += xSpeed; y += ySpeed;`. Flipping is reduced to `xSpeed *= -1`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems here:

- Since you're adding the same value, speed, to both x and y, your ball is always going to move at exactly a 45 degree angle.  Could be that's what you want, though...
- You're checking for x==0 and x==courtWidth, and reversing the directions at that time, but what if x=17, courtwidth=20, xDir =1, and speed=5?  When you increment x, it'll be 22, and it'll never exactly equal courtwidth and just keep incrementing forever. Somehow you have to handle the situation where it doesn't land exactly on the edge of the court.
- You might not want to flip both X and Y directions at all three walls -- if you do, the ball will bounce straight back the direction it came no matter where it hits

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I'm not sure as to how to implement that. Your third point I understand and i changed that